# Changing App name in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I´ve finished my quiz app a few days ago. Now, I want to publish a second quiz with different questions. I copied the project in Eclipse and changed the questions. Now, when install it on my smartphone, it tells me that this app is already there.

So where can I change the name that the two apps are different? Or do I have to change something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the package name:

```
 Right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application package
```

Comment: just refactoring the package names doesn't work so I came here.  This method works just dandy.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done it yet...
you need to change the package name like above but go into `strings.xml` and modify `"<string name="app_name">your app name </string>"` by changing simply the text that in this case says your app name.

Answer (score 1):

When you are testing, you can make do with uninstalling one and installing the other. However, if you intend to release two applications (or any number of applications) on Google Play, you should always have different package names for each.

The way the Google Play mechanism works is that different applications can have the same name. They are however, differentiated with their package names. No two applications on the Google Play store can share the same package names.

Here is a nice article titled, [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) by *Dianne Hackborn*.

Of course, use this (**as already answered by Nunu**), to change the Package name of your second application:
**Right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application package**

Answer (score 0):

It may be in the AndroidManifest.xml -> Application. pls have a look

```
 <application
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
```

also in the XML

Answer (score 0):

Your pakage name is same.
1. Try to uninstall older one and then re install 
2. or install it by simply changing your pakage name

Answer (score 0):

You Need to change name of your main package name , here the app name should be same but package name should not !